# How to print text files from folder through Java interface

Tags: java, file-io

I am building a GUI that will read from a text file then generate and write alpha-numeric codes to a text document (.txt) based on user input. I have read a good deal on how to print text files from Java using declarations under the "public static void main(String args []){" section using, by way of example (I understand this may not work and is not my code):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
FileInputSteam fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
Doc txtDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, null, null);
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.creatPrintJob();
printJob.print(txtDoc, new HasPrintRequestAttributeSet());
fis.close();}
```

I haven't read too much about how to call up a file from a specific location in a folder, the same file created by the user input, and print it upon user command through the interface, though.

For instance, how do I make the above capable of working under a

```
private void printAllBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

sub-declaration that appears above the 'public static void main...' declaration?

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: for choosing files you can try JFileChooser.
have you tried putting all your code thats  inside the main in printAllBtnActionPerformed?

Comment: @CalS. Very strange question above... can't exactly get what you are asking. Did you just want to add the above code (located inside main method) to the method private void printAllBtnActionPerformed()? If you are asking what i think you are asking, you simply copy the code and move it into this method...

Comment: I guess I was also asking that, yes, that if I just moved it to the other section, would it work the same? I'll keep you updated if that works or not. Thank you both.

Comment: I would start with some basics if you don't understand how those "sections" work. http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson05.htm - The code you posted is part (there are several things missing so it won't work) for printing on an actual paper printer. Is that really what you wanted to do?

Comment: @zapl, Yes, that is what I wish to do. Create the file on demand and then print it out on demand. I understand the code won't work as stated, that was just an example. Thank you, I will review that.